# Distribute BlackBerry compiled app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have developed a BlackBerry project and now I want to send the compiled output, such as .cod, .alx or .jad, to a client so that he can check it.  This is similar to the ipa file for iPhone.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The document from RIM [How to Deploy and Distribute Applications](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/117/1/How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf) tells all.